# OCI8 no PHP 7 em Linux

Tags: php, oracle, linux

Estou com uma pequena bronca.. estou com um servidor rodando o Debian e instalei o Apache e o PHP 7, porém estou tendo problemas para ativar a conexão do Oracle Oci8, segui este tutorial [Instalando Oci8](http://vinteum.com/instalando-oci8-e-oracle-instant-client-no-ubuntu/)  até ai está tudo ok, fiz todos os procedimentos porém quando testo o phpinfo() para visualizar se foi realmente ativado não está aparecendo...

O que pode ter esquecido? Não tem erros, mas também não está ativado.

Será que comi bronha? Agradeço atenção!

Answer (score -1):

Estive com esse mesmo problema, só que no windows. Consegui resolver trocando a .dll do OCI. A dll do PECL parece está desatualizada ou com compilação errada daí um usuário daqui me indicou este [link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.1.3/), na minha pergunta, e funcionou perfeitamente. Talvez ajude.